# MYSQL sum of max score taken users list

Tags: mysql

I have following table

```
 CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`userid` varchar(11), `score` int, `type` varchar(22));
    
INSERT INTO Table1
    (`userid`, `score`,`type`)
VALUES
    (11, 2,'leader'),
    (11, 6,'leader'),
    (13, 6,'leader'),
    (15, 4,'leader'),
    (15, 4,'leader'),
    (12, 1,'leader'),
    (14, 1,'leader');
```

I need to get userid of the maximum score take user.
if the max score is the same for two or more  user need to get that userid also.

I have try following query

```
SELECT userid, sum(score) as totalScore 
FROM Table1 WHERE type = "leader" GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY totalScore DESC;
```

But it gets all user data, cant get the max score take the first two users id.

[image]

But I need to get only first two row of data ..

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, I suggest using the `RANK()` analytic function:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT userid, SUM(score) AS totalScore,
           RANK() OVER (ORDER BY SUM(score) DESC) rnk
    FROM Table1
    WHERE type = 'leader'
    GROUP BY userid
)

SELECT userid, totalScore
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need just top 2 records add limit in your query :

```
SELECT userid, sum(score) as totalScore 
FROM Table1 WHERE type = "leader" GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY totalScore DESC LIMIT 2;
```